# Does cache-control take headers into account when looking for existing caches?

Tags: http, browser-cache, cache-control

For example: I make a request to http://example.com/some/path with Accept-Header: text/html and the response specifies that the response should be cached. If i then make request to the same url but Accept-Header: application/json, will the cache be ignored as the headers have changed?

If this is not enabled by default, can it be done using entity tags or another cache feature?

[RFC 2616 sec. 13.5.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.5.1) Suggests that the Accept-header is part of the cache and therefore included in the validation but I can't find it explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server needs to indicate that the response varies based on the "Accept" header field. See https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#rfc.section.7.1.4